# How to set domain in service now

Tags: global, uipath, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to make an API call in an MSP instance in ServiceNow. While trying to retrieve some records like groups and domains I am getting only the records that are stored globally. Is there any way I can set the domain as global before making the API call?
I need to do same thing using Uipath.

How can I achieve that?